# How to define root volume size in AWS batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, size, volume, aws-batch

I'm using AWS Batch and I found the root volume size too low for my task.

I tried creating a new computing environment/job queue but there's not any option to set volume size. I tried changing launch configuration from [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/home?region=us-east-1#LaunchConfigurations:) but the new launch configuration and/or autoscaling group are not considered by AWS Batch. I probably have to change [dm.basesize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html) but it is unclear where this should be done.

So, I set up a custom AMI from Amazon 2 Linux with 500 GB of storage, and changed the `--storage-opt` with `dm.basesize=400GB` as indicated [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=811761#811761) but, although my instances are spawned, the jobs remain in RUNNABLE state indefinitely. I inspected the possible causes as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151332/why-are-aws-batch-jobs-stuck-in-runnable), but i) "Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address" is checked, ii) the image should be good (it has been validated when creating the environment and it can be spawned), iii) I have a limit of 5 instances for such instance type (but I am unable to run even 1), iv) my role permissions should be ok - I used the same roles with a default amazonlinux image successfully, v) insufficient resources (the instance get spawned so I think this should not be the problem), vi) connectivity - it should be working since the autoscaling group displays a successful state.

One possible solution may be to attach a specific AWS volume at runtime, but it would be limited and I'd like to find an automatic solution, since instead I'd have to manage several volumes for parallel execution.

I also tried executing the task by piping input from an s3 bucket, analyzing the data and piping output to a second s3 bucket but I get [Connection Reset by Peer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1434451/41977) error each time, probably because the task runs for too long (I also set `--cli-read-timeout` to 0 but it doesn't fix it at all).

Is there a way to configure root volume size for jobs in AWS batch?

Comment: Batch takes the AMI from ComputeResource.imageID -- do you have that set correctly?

Comment: I set it up from the computing environment, is it the same setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use an unmanaged compute environment. Unfortunately this ended up being poor advice because not only is creating your own unmanaged compute environment difficult and esoteric, and not only does it kind-of defeat the entire purpose of AWS batch, but there is a much better (and much simpler) solution.

The solution to this problem is to create an Amazon Machine Image that is dervied from the default AMI that AWS Batch uses. An AMI allows you to configure an operating system exactly how you want it by installing libraries, modifying startup scripts, customizing configuration files, and most importantly for our purposes: define the logical partitioning and mount points of data volumes.

**1. Choose a base AMI to start from, configure your instance**

The AMIs we want to base ourselves off of are the official ECS-optimized AMIs. [Take a gander at this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) to find which AMI you need according to the AWS region you are running on.

After identifying your AMI, click the “Launch instance” link in the righthand column. You’ll be taken to this page:

[image]

Choose the t2.micro instance type.

Choose `Next: Configuration Details`.

Give your instance an appropriate IAM role if desired. What constitutes “appropriate” is at your discretion. Leave the rest of the default options.
Click `Next: Add Storage`.

Now is where you can configure what your data volumes will look like on your AMI. This step also does not define the final volume configuration for your AMI, but I find it to be useful to configure this how you want. You will have the opportunity to change this later before you create your AMI. Once you’re done, click `Next: Add Tags`.

Add any tags that you want (optional). Click `Next: Configure Security Group`.

Select `SSH` for `Type`, and set the Source to be `Anywhere`, or if you are more responsible than me, set a specific set of IP ranges that you know you will be using to connect to your instance. Click `Review and Launch`.

This page will allow you to review the options you have set. If everything looks good, then `Launch`. When it asks for a keypair, either select and existing keypair you’ve created, or create a new one. Failing to do this step will leave you unable to connect to your instance.

**2. Configure your software environment**

After you have clicked launch, go to your EC2 dashboard to see your running instances:

[image]

Wait for your instance to start, then right click it. Click `Connect`, then copy-paste the Example ssh command into an ssh-capable terminal. The `-i "keyname.pem"` is actually a path to your .pem file, so make sure you either `cd` to your `~/.ssh` directory, or change the flag’s value to be the path to where you stored your private SSH key. You also may need to change “root” to “ec2-user”.

[image]

After you have logged in, you can configure your VM however you want by installing any packages, libraries, and configurations you need your VM to have. If you used the AWS-provided ECS-optimized AMI, your AMI will already meet the base requirements for an ECS AMI. If you for some (strange) reason choose not to use the ECS-optimized AMI, you will have install and configure the following packages:

1. The latest version of the Amazon ECS container agent
2. The latest version of the ecs-init agent
3. The recommended version of Docker for your version of the ECS container agent.

Also note that if you want to attach another volume separate from your root volume, you will want to modify the `/etc/fstab` file so that your new volume is mounted on instance startup. I refer you to Google on how to do this.

**3. Save your AMI**

After all of your software configuration and installation is done, go back to your EC2 dashboard and view your running instances.

Right click on the instance you just made. Hover over `Image`, then select `Create Image`.

[image]

You’ll see that this has the volume configuration you chose in Step 1. I did not change my volumes from their default settings, so you can see in the screenshot above that the default volumes for the ECS-optimized AMI are in fact 8GB for `/dev/xvda/` (root), and 22GB for `/dev/xvdc/` (docker images, etc). Ensure that the `Delete on Termination` options are selected so that your Batch compute environment removes the volumes after the instances are terminated, or else you’ll risk creating an unbounded number of EBS volumes (very expensive, so I’m told). I will configure my AMI to have only 111GB of root storage, and nothing else. You do not necessarily need a separate volume for Docker.

Give your image a name and description, then select `Create Image`.

Your instance will be rebooted. Once the instance is turned off, AWS will create an image of it, then turn the instance back on.

In your EC2 console, go to `Images, AMIs` on the left hand side. After a few minutes, you should see your newly created AMI in the list.

[image]

**4. Configure AWS Batch to use your new AMI**

Go back to your AWS dashboard and navigate to the AWS Batch page. Select `Compute environments` on the left hand side. Select `Create environment`.

[image]

Configure your environment by selecting the appropriate IAM roles for both your container (Service Role) and EC2 instance (Instance role), provisioning model, networking, and tags.

```
Option                             Value

Compute environment type          Managed
Compute environment name          ami_test
Service role                      AWSBatchServiceRole
Instance role                     ecsInstanceRole
EC2 key pair                      landonkey.pem (use name of your private key)
Provisioning model                On-Demand (choose spot for significantly cheaper provisioning)
Allowed instance types            Optimal
Minimum vCPUs                     0
Desired vCPUs                     0
Maximum vCPUs                     256
Enable user-specified Ami ID      True
AMI ID                            [ID of AMI you generated]
VPC id                            [default value]
Subnets                           [select all options]
Security groups                   default
```

The critical step for this is selecting `Enable user-specified Ami ID` and specifying the AMI ID you generated in previous steps.

Once all of your options are configured, select `Create`.

**5. Create job queues and job definitions**

In order to test that our compute environment actually works, let’s go ahead and create some simple queues and job definitions.

Select `Job queues` on the left hand side and enter the following options:

```
Option                                  Value

Queue name                            ami_test_queue
Priority                              1
Enable Job queue                      True
Select a compute environment          ami_test
```

Select `Create`. Wait for the Status on your new queue to be `VALID`.

Go to `Job definitions` and select `Create`. Enter the following values:

```
Option                           Value

Job definition name            ami_test_job_def
Job role                       ECS_Administrator
Container image                amazonlinux
Command                        df -h
vCPUs                          1
Memory (MiB)                   1000
Job attempts                   1
Execution timeout              100
Parameters                     [leave blank]
Environment variables          [leave blank]
Volumes                        [leave blank]
Mount points                   [leave blank]
```

Select `Create job definition`.

Finally, go to `Jobs` on the left hand side and select `Submit job`. Give your job a name and select the `ami_test_job_def:1` for the Job definition. Leave the rest of the default values and select `Submit job`.

If all goes well, you should now see that your job has entered either the `Pending` or `Runnable` states. Note that it may take upwards of 10 minutes before your job actually runs. The EC2 instance typically takes 5-10 minutes to be instantiated, and a few more minutes to pass status checks. If your job continues to be in the `Runnable` state after the instance has been created and has passed all status checks. Something has gone wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have two concerns: i) In the job definition you defined as container image `amazonlinux` - shouldn't that be the image created through building the Dockerfile? ii) Did you check if the docker container, even if it runs flawlessly, can have access to the whole 111 GB volume?

Comment: @gc5 Most Dockerfiles start from a parent image. If you need to completely control the contents of your image, you might need to create a base image instead. Here’s the difference:                 A parent image is the image that your image is based on. It refers to the contents of the FROM directive in the Dockerfile. Each subsequent declaration in the Dockerfile modifies this parent image. Most Dockerfiles start from a parent image, rather than a base image. However, the terms are sometimes used interchangeably.      A base image either has no FROM line in its Dockerfile, or has FROM scratch

Comment: To show a summary of the data used, use this command:     `docker system df` and For more detailed view: `docker system df -v`

Comment: Yes, I know thanks. But since you put `df -h` as command, I was wondering if you already checked from the output that the root volume size available to docker was the one you're expecting to have. It should be available from the logs.

Comment: The method described  only allows you to create statically-sized data volumes for your instances. This means that even if you intend for each container process to have access to 100GB of storage, it is possible that your processes will end up competing with other processes for the same 100GB.

Comment: This is because AWS Batch often places multiple container processes on the same EC2 instance if there is enough space. If you chose Optimal for your allowed instance type, this means that Batch could possibly choose some EC2 type capable of hosting dozens of container instances, thus splitting up your storage amongst all of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way to guarantee a specific volume size for each docker container? Because that is the main objective of the question.

Comment: One of the alternatives suggested on the AWS developer forums is to use AWS Lambda to dynamically create and mount data volumes on the instances created by Batch. This gives you more flexibility to create appropriately-sized volumes for a dynamically chosen instance type (in the case of the Optimal option). However, you have to decide for yourself if this extra effort is worth it, keeping in mind that Occam’s razor: “the simpler solution is usually the better one.”

Comment: Can you add at least the link to this solution to the answer? Thanks

Comment: Try this: [Building High-Throughput Genomic Batch Workflows on AWS: Batch Layer (Part 3 of 4)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-high-throughput-genomic-batch-workflows-on-aws-batch-layer-part-3-of-4/)

Comment: Maybe that AWS blog was modified after you posted the link, but it now does it the same way as details in this SO answer: 
While you can use default Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs with AWS Batch, you can also provide your own image in managed compute environments. Use this feature to provision additional scratch EBS storage on each of the instances that AWS Batch launches... The process for creating a custom AMI for AWS Batch is well-documented.... use the default Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux AMI as a base and change it in the following ways...

Answer (score 13):

You can use launch templates too now. In the launch template increase the root volume size. Then from job definition mount the local filesystem such as /mnt to docker.

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html

Comment: Here is a reference for EBS volumes: https://github.com/vfrank66/awsbatchlaunchtemplate

Comment: This is the current best answer to the question. Launch templates takes care of most of steps detailed in the other accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is guidance for this issue here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/batch-job-failure-disk-space/

Take the provided MIME multi-part file, which sets the Docker size to 20G, and base64 encode it. Ie. `Mime_file.txt | base64`

The resulting output is a string of numbers and letters. Input this string into the "UserData" field in the provided launch template, and save your launch template as a json. Then use the AWS CLI to register the launch template `aws ec2 --region [region] create-launch-template --cli-input-json file://launchtemplate.json`. Associate this launch template with your compute environment in Batch.

Comment: Sorry, to encode the MIME file, the command is `cat Mime_file.txt | base64`

Comment: Here is an example for a `launchtemplate.json`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html